# How to merge same account with multiple contact in apex class?

Tags: apex, controller, class, loop, insert

I am inserting Invoice based on my attendees object and inserting Invoice Line item based on that Invoice that is already created.

so, My question is if the user will select multiple attendees, many of those might be at the same account, so we’ll make only one invoice for each account, but there will be an Invoice Line Item for each attendee.

This account is selected as per the contact of attendees record.

Please suggest me how can i do this.

Here is my code :

```
Public PageReference save(){

        invList = new List<Invoice__c>();
        invLineList = new List<Invoice_Line__c>();
        List<Attendee__c> attendeeUpdate = new List<Attendee__c>();

        Map<String,Attendee__c> invoiceAttendee = new Map<String,Attendee__c>();

        for(Attendee__c a : atList){

            Invoice__c inv = new Invoice__c();

            inv.Billed_Through__c = a.Function__r.Billed_Through__c;
            inv.Invoice_Memo__c = a.Function__r.Name;
            inv.Customer__c = a.Contact__c;
            inv.Invoice_Date__c = date.today();
            inv.AtndID__c = a.Id;
            invList.add(inv);
            invoiceAttendee.put(a.Id,a);
        }

        insert invList;

        for(Invoice__c inv : invList){
            if(invoiceAttendee.get(inv.AtndID__c) != null){
                invoiceAttendee.get(inv.AtndID__c).Invoice__c = inv.Id;
            }
        }

        update invoiceAttendee.values();

        for(Invoice__c i : invList){

            invLine = new Invoice_Line__c();
            invLine.Line_Description__c = ' Attendance of ' + invoiceAttendee.get(i.AtndID__c).Contact__r.Name  + ' at '+  invoiceAttendee.get(i.AtndID__c).Function__r.Name;
            invLine.Line_Total__c =  invoiceAttendee.get(i.AtndID__c).Attendee_Charge__c;
            invLine.invoice__c = i.Id;
            invLineList.add(invLine);
            if(invIDs == null){
                invIDs = i.id;
            }else{
                invIDs += ',' + i.id;  
            }

        }

        insert invLineList;
```

Comment: So if there are multiple attendees for one account, what do you want to the related invoice.AtndID__c field to be? First come first serve?

Comment: yes exactly. one account have only one invoice and that is FCFS. (but insert invoice line item for each attendees)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a map to capture whether an invoice has already been created for that account.

```
    Map<Id, Invoice__c> accountToInvoice = new Map<Id, Invoice__c>();

    for(Attendee__c a : atList){
        Invoice__c inv = accountToInvoice.get(a.Account);
        if(inv != null) 
            continue;

        inv = new Invoice__c();

        inv.Billed_Through__c = a.Function__r.Billed_Through__c;
        inv.Invoice_Memo__c = a.Function__r.Name;
        inv.Customer__c = a.Contact__c;
        inv.Invoice_Date__c = date.today();
        inv.AtndID__c = a.Id;
        invList.add(inv);
        invoiceAttendee.put(a.Id,a);
        accountToInvoice.put(a.Account, inv);
    }
```

For invoice line, just loop through attendee list instead of the invoice list. You should be able to accomplish the rest code.

```
for(Attendee__c a : atList) {
        Invoice__c inv = accountToInvoice.get(a.Contact__r.AccountId);
        invLine = new Invoice_Line__c(); // This line added
        invLine.Line_Description__c = ' Attendance of ' + a.Contact__r.Name  + ' at '+  a.Function__r.Name;
        invLine.Line_Total__c =  a.Attendee_Charge__c;
        invLine.invoice__c = inv.Id;
        invLineList.add(invLine);
        if(invIDs == null){
            invIDs = inv.id;
        }else{
            invIDs += ',' + inv.id;  
        }
    }  
    insert invLineList;
```

Comment: So, i have to create one more loop for Invoice Line (except existing). right ?

Comment: I have done that Account scenario. it is helpful. thanks. (for that invoice line i am confused because invoice line is create based on the invoice and we have inserting only one invoice for one Account.

Comment: @Nihar Edited my answer to include that. Honestly, that should be easy enough..

Comment: still i am not able to create that invoice line under that single invoice. sorry to disturb you but i am in beginner level.

Comment: @Nihar Edited. But I really don't understand what is the issue. Should be pretty straight forward

Comment: Hey Lance, I did this before you edited your answer. but i did one silly mistake. Let me edit your answer for line item and solve my problem. Thank you so much. :)